# which php\mysql query is more proper

Tags: php, mysql

I'm still learning and don't know which PHP\MySQL query is more proper? they both work fine but I'm using second one

```
$query = "SELECT Id, username, email FROM members";
$result = $conn->query($query);
  if ($result) {
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

or

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Id, username FROM members");

if ($query) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is object oriented PHP with mysqli better than the procedural approach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710195/why-is-object-oriented-php-with-mysqli-better-than-the-procedural-approach)

Comment: They are both equally fine. Depends on wider context, which one would be more appropriate for the current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is subjective (matter of opinion).

The first code snippet is Object Orientated, the second is Procedural.  If I were you, I'd use whichever code style you use in the rest of your project, neither is "better", although some would probably argue that OO is better practice.