# PHP Calling a function inside a class in an external file, Syntax?

Tags: php, function, class, mysqli

I have this external file CreateConnection.php that has a class DBController and its following functions. The createconnection file encounters no errors.

**CreateConnection.php** file inside

```
<?php
class DBController
{
    private $servername = "localhost";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $database = "mydatabase";

    function mainConnect()
    {
        //call the function connectDatabase to $connect
        $connect = $this->connectDatabase();

       //call the function selectDatabase
        $this->selectDatabase($connect);

        if(!$connect)
        {
            //Otherwise, prompt connection failed
            die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }

    function connectDatabase()
    {
        //Create connection
        $connect = mysqli_connect($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password);
        return $connect;
    }

    function selectDatabase($connect)
    {
         //Select database
         mysqli_select_db($connect, $this->database);
    }
}
?>
```

In this file, I include the external CreateConnection.php , but my '*$connect*' encounters many errors when calling the mainConnect() function.
**Process.php** file

```
<?php
    include("CreateConnection.php");
    $DBHandler = new DBController();

    $connect = $DBHandler->mainConnect();

    //Get values from form LoginReminder.php file
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['password']);
    //Removes back slashes in input
    $username = stripcslashes($username);
    $password = stripcslashes($password);

    //Query the database for users
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,"select * from tablereminders where username = '$username' and password = '$password' ");

    //Error connection and query
    if (!$result)
    {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connect));
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Does my syntax is incorrect since I've encountered this many errors when submitting a form:

**Errors**

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web Php Tutorial\LoginProcess.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web Php Tutorial\LoginProcess.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web Php Tutorial\LoginProcess.php on line 15

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web Php Tutorial\LoginProcess.php on line 20
```

Comment: `$connect` not return in `Mainconnect()` function

Comment: Should `stripcslashes` be being used after `mysqli_real_escape_string`? Passwords also should be hashed.

Comment: if `$connect` exist in mainConnect() , return it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `return $connect;` at the end of `function mainConnect(){` and you are fine.

But why do you not use OOP Version of MYSQLi at all?

[mysqli, OOP vs Procedural](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209409/mysqli-oop-vs-procedural)

```
class DBController
{ 
   private $db;

   private $servername = "localhost";
   private $username = "root";
   private $password = "";
   private $database = "mydatabase";

   function __construct(){
      $this->db = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password);
      $this->db->select_db($this->database);
   }
   function db(){
      return $this->db;
   }

}
$connection = new DBController();

#now instead of  using mysqli_query();
$connection->db()->query('SQL QUERY');
```

And a file thats holding only a class should have this as name:

Instead of `CreateConnection.php`  better `DBController.php`

The filename sounds like it will create a connection when its included, but that not the case :)

Comment: Hmm, is this not a good practice to use class for the connection sir? Some say that the best way is to use PDO.

Comment: It is a good pratice, but MYSQLi itself has classes. So to build your DBConnector you better use the class version of it.

Comment: `PDO` or `MYSQLi` is currently your choice, but never use `MYSQL` and try to avoid *procedural* useage.  Pin my answer as right, if i helped :)

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano If you need to roll your own, try `extend`-ing the class instead of wrapping it. It works better that way